# sin_addr always return 0.0.0.0

Tags: sockets, serversocket

Currently we are working on basic stuffs of sockets...I am completely new to sockets. My problem is, I am always getting the socket source address as 0.0.0.0..Can anyone help me resolve the issue. below is the code snippet

```
int main(int argc, char argv[])
{   
    struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;
    int s, i, slen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) , recv_len;
        unsigned char buf[BUFLEN];
        char cmd[2048];

    if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Failed to open socket:");
        return -1;
    }
    memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));
    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if( bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me) ) == -1)
    {
        perror("Failed to bind socket:");
        close(s);
        return -1;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr )&si_other, &slen)) == -1)
        {
            perror("Failed to recv:");
            close(s);
            return -1;
        }

        / print details of the client/peer and the data received /    

    printf( "Received packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr), ntohs(si_other.sin_port));
```

inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr) ---> always return 0.0.0.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: What port are you listening to?

Comment: @EJP that has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: @karthiick Where is the source data coming from?  Another app on the same machine? Or over the network? That can have an affect on the source IP that is reported.

Answer (score 0):

Warnings are not to be ignored!

Unrelated, but this is incorrect: `int main(int argc, char argv[])`. The second parameter of `main` is expected to be a `char **`, not a `char *`. You should write

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

or simply

```
int main()
```

if you do not intend to process the command line.

This is unrelated with your question, except that the problem is caused by a similar mistake:

```
recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr )&si_other, &slen))
```

you erroneously cast `&si_other` to a `struct sockaddr`, when what is expected is a **pointer** `struct sockaddr *`. I have just rewritten that line as:

```
    if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&si_other, &slen)) == -1)
```

and I immediately got the origin address.

BTW casting pointer in not recommended either, so you should have `slen` be a `socklen_t` (or at least `unsigned int`) and not an `int`.

Comment: Yes, we have done that (struct sockaddr *). Still facing the issue :(

Comment: @karthickJeyaram: I cannot reproduce. What is your environment (OS, compiler), and what kind of network are you using (loopback interface, other)?

Comment: This cast would not cause this problem. It doesn't change the address that is passed to `recv()`.

Comment: Plus, the original cast to `sockaddr` instead of `sockaddr*` was erroneous anyway, so the compiler should have refused to compile the code at all, let alone run it. You can't pass a `sockaddr` where a `sockaddr*` is expected.